# Compact boxplot does not align outliers

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, boxplot

I'd like to use the **compact** style box whisker plots in MATLAB. However, the outliers are not aligned with the main body. When using traditional style, it works just fine.

```
X = [rand(1, 100), -5, 5];

figure
boxplot(X, 'PlotStyle','traditional');
hold on
boxplot(X, 'PlotStyle','compact');
```

See figure:

**Overlay of compact vs traditional boxplots**

[image: overlay of compact vs traditional boxplots in matlab]

I am using Matlab R2014b on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the [`Jitter` parameter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/boxplot.html#input_argument_namevalue_jitter) to specify that you want no jitter in the x position of your outlier positions.

```
boxplot(X, 'PlotStyle', 'Compact', 'Jitter', 0)
```

[image]

A `Jitter` value greater than 0 is used to ensure that you can properly visualize all outliers, particularly those which would be completely overlapping  (i.e. have the same value)